# Good student but terrible test taker?

Tags: exams

So I am gradute student in theoretical computer science.

Throughout my education path up to highschool, I have all been praised a big lot by my teachers, some of them even went to such lengths as to say I was the most intelligent student they have ever taught. By dint of all that, I took it for granted that I must be cleverer than average and before I noticed, I might have gotten on a very high horse.

Then I got into college, and things started getting harder. The higher the horse, the bigger and harder the fall. So my grades stopped being close to full score, but not bad at all. Until I decided that I wanted to do a PhD later, and for that, I have to get very good marks and hope to get a scholarship.

Ever since, at the dawn of every test/exam, as opposed to the relaxed and cool mindset I'd be in before, I get very, very, VERY anxious and very flustered, either out of fear that I run out of time (because of a lived experience), or of not having the answer. That anxiousness would get lifted immeditely when time is up, and on my way back home, all answers or most of them, would start flowing in my head.

Only this morning, I had a test which I failed like never before. I quickly glossed over problems one by one in order, my mind would go blank for a few seconds, then I would deciddeto move on to the next problem and that it is no use wasting time on this one (because I wasn"'t going to find a solution), and that for every exercise. It is for a reason I say I failed today's like never before because I literally could do nothing; my mind was paralyzed and started weating and how I was going to not get to what I want to (PhD). But as soon as I got home and sat down for a few minutes, I solved prefectly 5 problems out 7  in 30 minutes (the test was to do within 90 minutes).

I was one of the most confident people in themselves before, but now I lost every bit of that confidence and wouldn't stop thinking I'm too dumb to make it. I have been struggling with this for two years now, and after today's huge blow, I decided to take to the internet and this board in order to try and find a solution. Chances are Academia is not the right board to ask this question in, but it must be the closest to that out of all other SE boards.

What can I do about my test taking so that my scores are more reflective of my natural ability?

Comment: As a *graduate student* the **grades are now completely irrelevant** to you --- your goal is to do superb research on timescale of years. You might take courses to learn something, but you do it for yourself now. Tests are just for fun from now on.

Comment: @BorisBukh ... But, since user is not yet a graduate student, grades may be important.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: @GEdgar The first sentence is "So I am gradute student in theoretical computer science. "

Comment: @BorisBukh: Except that many graduate programs have qualifying exams, which are definitely not "just for fun".

Comment: Anxiety around tests is very common.  Have you considered consulting a psychologist or similar professional?

Comment: In many US institutions, if you are diagnosed with anxiety disorder or ADHD (two most common diagnoses, although others surely exist) the university usually accommodates you by giving extra time (x1.5 is fairly common). I'm guessing that you're a Brit so I'm not sure if this answer is super relevant to you, but you should look into it.

Comment: What you are experiencing is not good for you in so many ways -- including your physical health.  Please print out your question and take it to see a doctor.  You could start with a GP (family practice doctor).  There are three prongs to explore: cognitive-behavioral treatment for your test anxiety, POSSIBLY medication, and documentation to get needed accommodations.  Note, the exact accommodations YOU need will depend on the particulars of YOUR situation.  For some students, extra time, separate location and breaks every 40 minutes are not sufficient.  Keep us updated.

Comment: @NateEldredge The qualifying exams are a filter. In all the universities I have been, I have never seen a research-capable student being filtered out by them. So, focusing on the research over tests is the correct approach.

Comment: @BorisBukh: My experience differs.  A student who is otherwise research capable, but for whatever reason is not able to pass the qualifying exams, is not allowed to continue in the program.

Comment: I have (hopefully) clarified the question and wonder if it can be re-opened in its current form?

Comment: @BorisBukh Graduate student could also be at the Master's level -- at my university research was about 10% of the MS program in CS, with exams being the other 90%. We can't assume all graduate exams are "just for fun."

Answer (score 7):

I too went through a period where I panicked when taking tests. I saw a psychologist for help. Even if you choose not to go that route, you might find my experience helpful.

The problem began when I started taking the kind of tests where even the best students may not be able to answer all of the questions. I'd look at question one, not know how to answer it (at least, not right away), and begin to get nervous. Question two might seem daunting as well, so I'd become even more nervous. By the time I'd looked at question three, I was convinced that I would fail. Eventually I might realise that I knew how to do part of one of the questions. That gave me confidence to tackle another piece of another question, and so on. But I spent too much time panicking to do well on most tests.

The key for me in overcoming this was to realise that it was normal to not know how to answer any of the questions at first. I learned to expect it, but also to expect that after a couple of minutes I would begin to get ideas for solutions. By *expecting* that I would draw a blank at first, while realising that this wouldn't mean I'd fail the test, I kept myself from panicking.

Part of what the psychologist did was to help me understand this. The other thing was that he worked with me to visualise the test-taking procedure:
sitting down at the desk, turning over the paper, scanning the list of questions, not knowing how to answer any of them, then getting an idea, and so on. He talked me through the scenario while I did some relaxation exercises that he taught me.

Take comfort in the fact that your test-taking days are almost over. After you get a postgraduate degree, no one cares whether you passed with flying colours or barely squeaked by. Your publications will be far more important.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information in your question, your strength is "project" work, and your weakness is taking tests.

In high school,the strength of your project work stood out, and tests didn't stand in your way.

In early college, your weakness at test-taking kept you from getting the highest scores, but your project work bailed you out. Now, the equation no longer holds.

The solution is twofold: The first is to take courses that emphasize project work and de-emphasize test-taking.

The second is to take a "test-prep" course, or even get pychological/testing counseling, so that you will "pass" your tests to a degree that will let your project strengths speak for you.